# Why can't I run nmap with the -O option even when I use sudo

Tags: networking, permissions, sudo, nmap

I'm trying to determine which ports are in use with my machine. I found, online an article that listed one method as follows:

```
$ sudo nmap -sT -O localhost
```

I believedthis would give me a list of all ports listening for TCP packets. However, when I enter this command, I get the following result:

```
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-02 21:07 EDT
socket troubles in HostOsScan: Permission denied (13)
```

If I'm running as sudo, how can I lack permission to run something on my machine??

I tried running just:

```
$ sudo nmap -sT  localhost
```

and got:

```
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-02 21:28 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000094s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
631/tcp open  ipp
```

Just tried `nmap` without arguments and again was denied permission !?

```
$ sudo nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-03 11:05 EDT
Couldn't open a raw socket. Error: Permission denied (13)
```

Looking at `nmap's` `--help` option, I see that `-O` enables OS detection. Why should I not have permission to use this option - especially with `sudo`? (Note: I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04)

(Note: Accepted answer solves my root problem - looking at ports, but answer in comments section explains why I was having trouble with `nmap`. Apparently, because I installed with `snap`, I needed to also execute:

```
 $ sudo snap connect nmap:network-control
```

before `nmap` would work correctly

Comment: if you are using snap to provide nmap it's time to tell it.

Comment: @A.B - I realize this shows how little I know, but what do you mean "using snap to provide nmap"??

Comment: If `dpkg -S /usr/bin/nmap` returns a line starting with nmap: then it's not through snap.

Comment: @A.B. Apparently, I did install nmap with snap - which nmap returns /snap/bin/nmap. So, what should I do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031714/why-is-nmap-not-working-in-18-04/1312647#1312647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you're trying to determine which ports are in use with your machine you don't need to scan. You can just list the ports directly

```
netstat -nap
ss -nap
```

If you're not root omit the `-p` flag. The `LISTEN` lines are the important ones for you, and you can filter for these with `awk`. For example

```
netstat -nap | awk 'NR==1 || /LISTEN/'
```

Answer (score -1):

First "I'm trying to determine which ports are in use with my machine." then drop the -O since you don't need to know what your local OS is.

Might need more information.

1. What OS are you running? Maybe include which kernel
2. Are you running a firewall? or Fail2ban or any related security services?
3. Can you install older version? My install in Nmap v7.80 from Ubuntu repo didn't show the same issue.
4. Are you in a Virtual Machine, VPS, or hosted system?
5. Is this a clean install with little to no installed programs? If so you have a quiet system, not much noise, not much to detect.
6. Tried other OS detection Nmap options? --osscan-limit --osscan-guess --max-os-tries [LINK](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html)

Lack of detected TCP ports makes OS detection difficult. Replies to TCP request is how OS detection works. Better explained here https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-methods.html